# How can I run a Selenium test in a single Perl file for several URLs?

Tags: perl, selenium-rc

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::HiRes qw(sleep);
use Test::WWW::Selenium;
use Test::More "no_plan";
use Test::Exception;
my $sel = Test::WWW::Selenium->new(
    host        => "localhost",
    port        => 4444,
    browser     => "*firefox",
    browser_url => "http://10.201.3.192:8000/"
);
$sel->open_ok("/abc-dd/");
$sel->window_maximize();
$sel->$sel->$sel->$sel->_ok();
$sel->close_ok();
```

The above code works fine for a single URL. I need to perform the same operation on another URL. The following code completed execution of only the first part.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::HiRes qw(sleep);
use Test::WWW::Selenium;
use Test::More "no_plan";
use Test::Exception;
my $sel = Test::WWW::Selenium->new(
    host        => "localhost",
    port        => 4444,
    browser     => "*firefox",
    browser_url => "http://10.201.3.192:8000/"
);
$sel->open_ok("/abc-dd/");
$sel->window_maximize();
$sel->$sel->$sel->$sel->_ok();
$sel->close_ok();
$sel->open_ok("http://10.201.3.195:8000/abc-dd/");
$sel->window_maximize();
$sel->$sel->$sel->$sel->_ok();
$sel->close_ok();
```

I have to perform operations on two URLs in a single Perl file:

```
http://10.201.3.192:8000/abc-dd/
http://10.201.3.195:8000/abc-dd/
```

How can I append the second URL?

Answer (score 1):

You can make an array of urls and loop through it

```
my @urls = qw (http://10.201.3.192:8000 
               http://10.201.3.195:8000); # create list of urls

for my $url (@urls) {

    my $sel = Test::WWW::Selenium->new( host => "localhost", 
                                    port => 4444, 
                                    browser => "*firefox", 
                                    browser_url => $url );

    $sel->open_ok("/abc-dd/");
    $sel->
    $sel->
    ...
}
```

Comment: @ ccheneson : 
When it encounters the another URL appended, thrown an error as


 

Error requesting http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/
 ERROR: Current window or frame is closed!
 not ok 11 - open, http://10.201.3.195:8000/abc-dd/
 Failed test 'open, http://10.201.3.195:8000/abc-dd/'

Comment: I havent worked for a long tme with perl test and never with Selenium but you can try calling your test script from another script that would pass the url to test.

Comment: @ ccheneson : After modifying the code as per your suggestion,got error as

C:\Scripts>perl final.pl
Error requesting http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/:
Failed to start new browser session: Error while launching browser
# Looks like your test exited with 255 before it could output anything.

Comment: @ ccheneson : Should i need to insert comma(,) to separate URLs ? my @urls = qq (http://10.201.3.192:8000                 http://10.201.3.195:8000);

Comment: No, you shouldnt need. Unfortunately, i dont have any environment to do any test

Comment: @ccheneson: probably you meant qw(...) instead of qq(...)

Answer (score 1):

Pack your logic into function for reuse:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::HiRes qw(sleep);
use Test::WWW::Selenium;
use Test::More "no_plan";
use Test::Exception;

sub test_url {
    my $sel = Test::WWW::Selenium->new( host => "localhost", 
                                        port => 4444, 
                                        browser => "*firefox", 
                                        browser_url => "http://10.201.3.192:8000/" );

    $sel->open_ok("/abc-dd/");
    $sel->window_maximize();
    $sel->
    $sel->
    $sel->
    $sel->_ok();
    $sel->close_ok();
}

test_url("/abc-dd/");
test_url("http://10.201.3.195:8000/abc-dd/");
```

Comment: @ Oleg V. Volkov : getting error after executing as above Unrecognized character \x93; marked by <-- HERE after test_url(<-- HERE